# C linking error (with tcc)

Tags: c, linker-errors, undefined-symbol, tcc, lib

I'm trying to run the example from [tiny cc](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/tinycc/) *(tcc-0.9.26-win64-bin.zip)* called `libtcc_test.c`.

I've copied `libtcc.h` from `libtcc` into `include` and `libtcc.def` into `lib`.
Then I ran `tcc ./examples/libtcc_test.c` and got a linking error :/

```
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_new'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_set_lib_path'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_set_output_type'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_compile_string'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_add_symbol'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_relocate'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_get_symbol'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_delete'
```

What am I missing ?

---

**More info:**

```
P:\cpp\tcc>tcc ./examples/libtcc_test.c -vv
tcc version 0.9.26 (i386 Win32)
-> ./examples/libtcc_test.c
-> p:/cpp/tcc/include/stdlib.h
->  p:/cpp/tcc/include/_mingw.h
->   p:/cpp/tcc/include/stddef.h
->   p:/cpp/tcc/include/stdarg.h
->  p:/cpp/tcc/include/limits.h
->  p:/cpp/tcc/include/sec_api/stdlib_s.h
->   p:/cpp/tcc/include/stdlib.h
->  p:/cpp/tcc/include/malloc.h
-> p:/cpp/tcc/include/stdio.h
->  p:/cpp/tcc/include/vadefs.h
->  p:/cpp/tcc/include/sec_api/stdio_s.h
->   p:/cpp/tcc/include/stdio.h
-> p:/cpp/tcc/include/string.h
->  p:/cpp/tcc/include/sec_api/string_s.h
->   p:/cpp/tcc/include/string.h
-> p:/cpp/tcc/include/libtcc.h
-> p:/cpp/tcc/lib/libtcc1.a
-> p:/cpp/tcc/lib/msvcrt.def
-> p:/cpp/tcc/lib/kernel32.def
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_new'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_set_lib_path'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_set_output_type'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_compile_string'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_add_symbol'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_relocate'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_get_symbol'
tcc: error: undefined symbol 'tcc_delete'
```

Comment: Well you need to link against the libs and include files, to compile your code. Make sure you link and include with necessary libs and headers.

Comment: I'm very new to c but there is #include "libtcc.h" and tcc ... -vv also output says that it is added but I don't know how to "load" .def file

Comment: @LethalProgrammer: "*... need to link against the ... include files ...*" included (header) files aren't used during the linking phase, but only during compilation, which is done when it comes to linking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To link in a library, you need to add a `-l${library_basename}` flag after all `c` files or `o` files. 
If the library is named `libtcc.a` or `libtcc.so` (on Windows it's probably `tcc.dll` or `libtcc.dll`), you need to add `-ltcc`.

```
tcc  ./examples/libtcc_test.c  -ltcc
```

You might also need to add an `-L` flag to add a search path in case the library you want to link in is not your system's standard library directories:

```
tcc -L . ./examples/libtcc_test.c -ltcc
#also look for libtcc.so or libtcc.a in the current directory (.)
```

The `libtcc_test.c` from `test/libtcc_test.c` in the tinycc repo also needed the `dl` library (standard library for dynamic loading) to build:

```
tcc -L .  tests/libtcc_test.c  -ltcc -ldl #worked
```

(it complained about undefined `dlopen`, `dlclose`, and `dlsym` which are known to come from `libdl`).

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked on Windows:

```
cd your-tcc-directory
tcc -Ilibtcc -L. -ltcc examples/libtcc_test.c
```

You might want to add `-run` to skip generating exe file and running the source code directly.

I tried it on Linux, but it couldn't find `libtcc.h`. I guess the following will work (note `-ltcc1` instead of `-ltcc`):

```
tcc -I/path/to/libtcc.h/location -L/usr/lib/tcc/x86-64 -ltcc1 path/to/libtcc_test.c
```